# SQL Derived Table / Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

SQL 2005 :

I am working on set of SQL queries which generate a formula.

This Mathematical calculation, Example : (3000 -30)/1477*100   = 201.1 % has to be generated from set of Tables.

```
Value : 3000 is generated from this query ..
select sum(DaysSupply) as [Total Days Supply] from vOeOrderWide where patcustid = 4797 
Output is [Total Days Supply]


Value : 30 is generated from this query ..
select top 1 DaysSupply from VoeOrderwide where patcustid = 4797 order by datefilled desc
Output is [DaysSupply]

Value : 1477 is generated from these set of queries ...

declare @d1  datetime;
declare @d2  datetime;
set @d1= (select top 1 DateFilled from vOeOrderWide where patcustid = 4797 
order by DateFilled asc)
set @d2= (select top 1 DateFilled from vOeOrderWide where patcustid = 4797 order by DateFilled DESC )
select DATEDIFF(d,@d1,@d2) as [Days Between] 

Output is [Days Between]

I want to combine all these queries and generate the formula as ..

[Total Days Supply] - [DaysSupply]  /  [Days Between]  * 100
```

Comment: You have the code so what is the question again?

Comment: In this patcustid = 4797 , i am passing as Input Parameter. I am trying to create this set of sql in a Stored procedure or User Defined function !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I think I'd try something more along these lines:

```
WITH supply_data (Total_Days_Supply, Earliest_Date_Filled, Latest_Date_Filled) as (
                  SELECT SUM(DaysSupply), MIN(DateFilled), MAX(DateFilled)
                  FROM voeOrderWide
                  WHERE patCustId = 4797)
SELECT 100.00 * ((Total_Days_Supply - (SELECT TOP 1 DaysSupply
                                       FROM voeOrderWide
                                       WHERE patCustId = 4797
                                       AND DateFilled = LatestDateFilled
                                       ORDER BY DateFilled DESC)) 
                 / DateDiff(d, Earliest_Date_Filled, Latest_Date_Filled))
FROM supply_data
```

Please note that I do not have an SQL server instance to test this against.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this?

```
DECLARE @TotalDaysSupply int, @DaysSupply int

select @TotalDaysSupply = sum(DaysSupply) as [Total Days Supply] from vOeOrderWide where patcustid = 4797 

SET @DaysSupply = (select top 1 DaysSupply from VoeOrderwide where patcustid = 4797 order by datefilled desc)

declare @d1  datetime;
declare @d2  datetime;
DECLARE @DaysBetween int

set @d1= (select top 1 DateFilled from vOeOrderWide where patcustid = 4797 
order by DateFilled asc)
set @d2= (select top 1 DateFilled from vOeOrderWide where patcustid = 4797 order by  DateFilled DESC )

select @DaysBetween = DATEDIFF(d,@d1,@d2)

--[Total Days Supply] - [DaysSupply]  /  [Days Between]  * 100

SELECT  CAST(@TotalDaysSupply AS float) - @DaysSupply/ @DaysBetween * 100 AS Result
```

Comment: select @TotalDaysSupply = sum(DaysSupply) as [Total Days Supply]   This syntax throws an exception !!

Comment: And the final formula you use (`totalDaysSupply - ((daysSupply / daysBetween) * 100)`) does *not* match the stated formula (`((totalDaysSupply - daysSupply) / daysBetween) * 100`).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this script without management studio. Your final formula was [Total Days Supply] - [DaysSupply]  /  [Days Between]  * 100. I thought something wrong with it, but guessed that you would figure it out.